# Convexity of a finite Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was wondering how to determine whether the following set is convex or not:

All $A_1, A_2,..., A_m $are convex sets:

$ \sum^m_{i=1} A_i = \{ x_1+x_2+...+x_m,$ $ x_i \in A_i, i=1,2,...,m\}$

can I apply the general theorem, $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y$?

Comment: Off topic, but think of disjoint sets ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any two points from $\sum_{i=1}^mA_i$ : $x$ which is of the form $x_1+\cdots+x_m$ and $y$ of the form $y_1+\cdots y_m$, where $x_i,y_i\in A_i$. Then 
$$\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y=\sum_{i=1}^m(\lambda x_i+(1-\lambda)y_i)$$
Now $x_i,y_i\in A_i$ implies $\lambda x_i+(1-\lambda)y_i\in A_i$. Hence $\lambda x+(1-\lambda) y\in \sum_{i=1}^mA_i$